# How to insert 30,000 record in SQLite database in iPhone it is possible in iPhone simulator not in Device it will crash

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite

Currently i have facing one problem i have to call web service and download the data from the server it is around 30,000 record, it is downloaded via server but when i am inserting record into SQLite 
but when start the inserting record in database it will increase the memory to 20 to 150 mb in instrument control and crash the application..

So please give me the solutions for the same..

Comment: How is the data coming in? XML?

Comment: Are you still facing this problem or is "Currently" no longer accurate. The link you provided pointed to spam.

Answer (score 1):

30,000 sounds like a lot.  I'd Do the work in chunks.

Comment: Exactly. However you've written it there's clearly some object that grows and grows or a bunch of objects you're creating and not releasing until the end. Refactor your code such that it's releasing those objects or, as Brad suggests, import, say, 3,000 records ten times.

Answer (score 0):

Would have to see your code to see what's going on. Run using Allocations or Leaks tool and maybe just run it for 5000 records. See what is using up memory.

Post your code.